# change controllers directory name in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controllers

is it possible to change the directory name of the Controllers / Views ... in asp.net MVC ? 
i mean I want to name the controllers folder to be "myControllers" or any other name, is it possible ? and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just rename the "Controllers" folder to what you want. This is doesn't valid for the view.

But I'd never recommend you changing ASP.NET convention.

Comment: Ok what about views? I know the controller thing ... i want to change the entire convention is it possible, and how ?

Comment: You can create your custom view engine and provide your `ViewLocationFormats`. See this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx)